# Elastic Search get count of unique parent ID in search results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an index:

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "teacher_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "school_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "height": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "family_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "studentID": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "performance_text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "highlight": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "store": true,
                            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
                        }                       
                    }
                },
                "_class": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "index": false,
                    "doc_values": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each document in my elastic search index represents a student. Logically, a school can have multiple teachers and a teacher can have multiple students. I perform the search on performance_text to get the search results. However, as a response to the search, I want the "count" of the unique school_ids (the parent id) and not just the students. How can I achieve that? What additions can I make below for the same?

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "performance_text": "search_term"
        }
    }
    "aggs": {
        "source": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "school_id",
                "size": 100000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want the list of all the unique school_ids that match the search critera like the code aove delivers. I just want the final count of the unique school_ids. Because fetching all the values of that field for large search responses on large collections and then calculating the count is time consuming.

Comment: Are you looking for cardinality aggs?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html